# Reliability of both the exit() and header() functions for system security

Tags: php, location, exit

Okay, so I have some code here:

```
<?php session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['blah'])) {
header('Location: foo.php'); exit();

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset = 'utf-8' />
<title>Check Login</title>
</head>
<body>
// members only content here
</body>
</html>
```

So, I've found a foolproof way around using either headers or exit statements for redirects (by echoing a particular document depending on the value of an if-else statement), but using headers is a lot cleaner than echoing an entire webpage in a heredoc. (I also know I should be using HTTPS for additional security).

I have two questions.

1. How widespread is browser support for the `Location` header? I know I can't use it on its own by reading similar questions, but I wouldn't mind knowing anyway.
2. Also, how reliable is the use of php's `exit()` function for maintaining system security? Does it always work, or should I just echo a HEREDOC instead when security really matters?

Comment: The `Location` header is supported by _*every*_ single browser in the world. It's part of the first HTTP specification. So yes, it *always* works. As for `exit` being secure... what do you mean? It stops execution at that point.... I don't see what that might have to do with system security?

Comment: So I'm guessing exit() stops a server from sending the rest of a particular page, and that would be foolproof. I'm looking at the PHP specification for exit now, so that will clear a bunch of stuff up.

Comment: Note that although most (all?) browsers support relative URIs in `Location` header like in your example, HTTP specification requires it to be absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually any browser existing today does support `Location`; However, you should be careful about which status code you send along with it (3rd parameter to `header`). See [rfc2616 sec10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for more information about which code to choose; 303 seems more correct but 302 is better supported.

How reliable `exit()` is, really depends on how reliable your server is. If your PHP code is executed, `exit()` will always abort execution and send the result to the browser. However, a wrongly configured webserver may directly expose your PHP code instead of executing it. [This comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.php) explains how you can mitigate this problem.

As for following the specs, [rfc2616 sec10](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) says:

> Unless the request method was HEAD, the entity of the response SHOULD contain a short hypertext note with a hyperlink to the new URI(s).

You can implement this by not using `exit()` but using `die('<a href="foo.php">You are redirected.</a>')` instead.